# Merge duplicated objects in javascript array with their appearance frequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

i have a javascript array who look like this

```
       [
         { quantity: 1, name: 'Menu sandwichs' },
         { quantity: 1, name: 'Menu sandwichs' },
         { quantity: 1, name: 'Menu sandwichs' },
         { quantity: 1, name: 'Pizza' },
         { quantity: 1, name: 'Piza' }

      ]
```

and i want to get this array

```
            [
             { quantity:3, name:'Menu Sandwich' },
             { quantity:2, name:'Pizza' }
            ]
```

Could you hel me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the quantities in the original array may sometimes be something other than 1:

```
const mergeQuantities = (values) => {
  const result = {}

  values.forEach(({ quantity, name }) => {
    result[name] = result[name] || { name, quantity: 0 }
    result[name].quantity += quantity
  })

  return Object.values(result)
}
```

This creates a new object where the attribute names are the `name` from each thing in the array. Then iterates over the list, adding each `quantity` to the result. Finally, it discards the keys, leaving just the array in the form you want.